# If file does not exists, rewrite

Tags: nginx

If the user types `www.mysite.com/foo.php`, if the file foo exist the server respond with foo, but if the file does not exist, it needs to rewrite like this: `www.mysite.com/url.php?url=foo.php`

Im trying this on nginx:

```
    location / {
            include /etc/nginx/global/*;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            if (!-e $request_filename){
              rewrite ^(.*)$ /url.php?url=$1 break;
            }
    }
```

But instead of rendering the page (when the file is not present), the browser downloads it. Why?

Comment: You need to be using `try_files`, not `rewrite`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add location for processing .php files, if not yet. And setup php-fpm too, of course.

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/global/*;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /url.php?url=$uri;
}

# something about
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /url.php?url=$uri;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: how can I handle index.html?

Comment: What about index.html?